# xargs: ggrep: no such file or directory

Tags: bash, cmd, git-bash

I use the following command in Git Bash to search for Java classes using non ASCII characters:

```
 find */src/*/java -name "*.java" -print0 | xargs -0 ggrep -lP "[\x80-\xFF]"
```

I get the error:

```
xargs: ggrep: no such file or directory
```

Any other way to run this command in Windows 7?

Comment: do you mean `grep` instead of `ggrep`?

Comment: If `ggrep` is an alias for `git grep`, well, you can't use aliases with xargs. Type `git grep` instead.